# Calculate elapsed time of Excel to insert row

Tags: excel, vba

We're having some performance problems with a massive worksheet. In particular, three operations seem very slow: insert row, delete row, and undo.

I've been reading about optimization and want to quantify which changes really make a difference. To do so, I'd like to setup some VBA that tracks elapsed time for the events listed above, but I can't find any hooks.

I'd like something like worksheet_change_start, worksheet_change_end, but I haven't found anything like that.

I had one "great" idea, but it didn't work. I thought I would do two insert rows back to back, take a time stamp at each one and then calculate the difference...but Excel outsmarted me and batched them together somehow.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions

**NOTE:** Thanks to the answers so far. I do know about the timer function, but I can't find out how to capture the events where I can start and end the timer for some user behavior, such as before and after the user inserts a row.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a small macro such as below to time how long it takes your workbook to perform the action

```
Dim t As Date
t = Now()
'your code for inserting new line here
MsgBox Format(Now() - t, "hh:mm:ss")
```

source: http://www.mrexcel.com/archive/VBA/20164.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a basic timer class (from a previous SO question - reference tba) by putting this into a **class module** (called `CTimer`). The benefit of this approach is its reusable.

```
Option Explicit

Private Type LARGE_INTEGER
    lowpart As Long
    highpart As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function QueryPerformanceCounter Lib "kernel32" (lpPerformanceCount As LARGE_INTEGER) As Long
Private Declare Function QueryPerformanceFrequency Lib "kernel32" (lpFrequency As LARGE_INTEGER) As Long

Private m_CounterStart As LARGE_INTEGER
Private m_CounterEnd As LARGE_INTEGER
Private m_crFrequency As Double

Private Const TWO_32 = 4294967296# ' = 256# * 256# * 256# * 256#

Private Function LI2Double(LI As LARGE_INTEGER) As Double
Dim Low As Double
    Low = LI.lowpart
    If Low < 0 Then
        Low = Low + TWO_32
    End If
    LI2Double = LI.highpart * TWO_32 + Low
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
Dim PerfFrequency As LARGE_INTEGER
    QueryPerformanceFrequency PerfFrequency
    m_crFrequency = LI2Double(PerfFrequency)
End Sub

Public Sub StartCounter()
    QueryPerformanceCounter m_CounterStart
End Sub

Property Get TimeElapsed() As Double
Dim crStart As Double
Dim crStop As Double
    QueryPerformanceCounter m_CounterEnd
    crStart = LI2Double(m_CounterStart)
    crStop = LI2Double(m_CounterEnd)
    TimeElapsed = 1000# * (crStop - crStart) / m_crFrequency
End Property
```

And then in an ordinary code **module** you can use it like this:

```
Sub test_time()
Dim time_this As New CTimer
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

time_this.StartCounter

    ws.Rows("6:6").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ws.Rows("8:8").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

MsgBox time_this.TimeElapsed

End Sub
```

Comment: It should be noted that those imported functions are for a 32-bit Excel/VBA. **PtrSafe** equivalents (or both versions with compiler directives) would be needed for a 64-bit Excel/VBA.